# What are some recommended ways to use git after importing an eclipse project into android studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, adt

I just imported my first android project into android studio from eclipse.  The process basically seems to have **copied** my code from the eclipse project into android studio.

The original git repository had a lot of history which I would like to try to maintain, if possible.

The original git repository had a structure like this

- project

  - src
  - res

The android studio project structure looks like this

- project

  - main

    - java
    - res

I think the only history I care about are the java:src and res:res directories.  I have test classes I have not moved over yet, but I don't think the history there is quite as important.

Is there a way to preserve the history for these source files and resources, or should I just "cut and run" ?   If there is a better way to do the import (other than following the wizard),  I am open to that, as other than figuring out how to use gradle rather than copying jars into my libs folder, the process was semi-painless (took a few hours but then again I am not expert at any of this stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took me a while, but in the end this is not too hard to do.

The basic idea is to create a .git directory that has all the existing history, but structure as what android studio uses, then copy that to your project root. It is a fairly easy process, but I wrote down every gory detail here. You could probably skip some of these steps (like making the new branches), but you can find the details in my answer to a related question, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626043/how-do-i-decouple-my-new-android-studio-repro-from-my-old-eclipse-repro)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. You should import your project by manual. Ok, follow my step:

1.Copy you Eclipse project to your Android Studio project root folder.

2.Modify the settings.gradle file(In your Android Studio project root folder), add following code:
include ':YourProjectName'

3.Add a build.gralde file to the project which your want to import, just like(This can keep your eclipse project structure):

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

}

4.Finally, clikc Buiild->Rebuild Project in toolbar, and you will see a *.iml file is auto generate.

Hoping this can help you!