# How do I "decouple" my new android studio repro from my old eclipse repro?

Tags: git

### Update

My intent with this question was to complete the migration of my eclipse project to Android Studio and keep all the file history.  I when to a path where I started with a clone of the eclipse project , but ran into the following issue.  I reworked this starting with a copy of the eclipse repro rather than a clone and managed to get exactly what I wanted (see my answer below)

### Original question:

I migrated my eclipse project to android studio.  In an attempt to retain the git history, I cloned the existing eclipse repo into a temp space /tmp/git_rename (for example)

In that cloned repro I did the following:

1. removed any files that would not be needed in Android studio (projects setting for example)
2. moved the source and resource directories to the locations they would be in android studio
   (for example I moved the contents of src to app/src/main/java)

I did this by creating a few new branches. committing and merging them back into master as I did it.

What I then had was a git repo that had the source files in the same locations at the source files in the migrated android studio project

I then copied this .git directory in the the root of my android studio directory

I think this did most of what I wanted (I can see the history of all my java and resource files).

The problem is that since I did a clone, all the old branches are just references to the old eclipse repo, as shown below.  I would really like this to be a "standslone" repository, with all the old branches, commits local to it.  I also have the problem that I have a local master and a remote master.  I would then push that to some remote for backups.

I imagine this should be fairly easy to do, but I am close to what I want, and I don't really want to break anything.

---

**Can someone give me some guidance on how to go from where I am (shown below) to a single repo with all the branches local and one master?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and did this from scratch one last time.  I will document what I did, hopefully it will help someone else find a good approach to migrate an eclipse ADT project to Android Studio and maintain all the git history (it was not obvious to me).

This assumes you have gone through the migration wizard and have an Android Studio version of your app migrated, but you now want to get all the git history moved over as well.
If you have not done that yet, it's fairly strait forward, you can start with the instructions on the developers page found [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Once you have completed the migration, you will have a **copy** of your source code in Android Studio, but no git history.  Here is how I got mine moved over.

The basic idea is to create a .git directory that has all the existing history, but structure as what android studio uses, then copy that to your project root.  It is a fairly easy process, but I wrote down every gory detail here.  You could probably skip some of these steps (like making the new branches), but this is what I did.

1. make sure you have every thing committed and are pointing to master in you eclipse repo
2. copy (via cp -rp , **not** git clone) your existing eclipse git repo to a temp area. Note you are copying the entire repo, all files, directories, etc including the .git directory
3. go to the temp area and use git to confirm that everything is there, ie no changes are pending
4. create and switch to a branch called delete_things_not_needed_in_A_S
5. use rm -r to remove anything that will not exist in android studio.  For me I was left with src, my manifest, and the .git directory (you could just selectively copy I guess, rather than copy and delete)
6. use git to commit these changes and merge them into master, then create a new branch called move_directories_to_match_as_structure.
7. now go into the temp area and create any directories need to match the Android Studio Structure. for example in AS the package root is under app/src/main/java vs in eclipse it is directly in the root of the project directory.
8. next move , using mv, the directories you are keeping into the locations they would exist in Android studio.  What you should end up with is a directory small subset of what you had in your eclipse repo, but the directories matching what AS is expecting.
9. remove any "left over" directories, such as the original src (you moved the contents of that to another location, but the directory still exists)
10. Do an final check, at this point you should only have the directories containing the files in which you want to retain the history for and the .git directory, nothing else.
11. using git, commit those changes, merge them in to master, and create (and switch to) a final new branch called files_added_by_android_studio
12. use cp -rp to copy (this is important) **ONLY** the .git directory into you android studio project root.  Note the only change you are making to the migrated android studio project is to copy the .git directory in.
13. create or or update your .gitignore files in the root of your android project directory and in the app subdirectory with what I have shown below.
14. in the root of you android studio project, use git gui (or git status) to confirm that there are only a hand full of new files
15. commit and merge them into master
16. start android studio and enable version control integration (under VCS on the main menubar)

That should do it.  It sounds more complicated than it really is.  Basically you are copying your existing .git folder , modifying it so that it expects to see the changes where they will occur in android studio rather than were they did occur in eclipse and then copying that modified .git folder into you android studio project.

Here are the two .gitignore files I used:

in the project root.

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
```

in the app folder:

```
/build
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is make your repo stop tracking its remotes, you can just delete the references to the remotes using `git remote rm [remotename]`. If `origin` is your only remote, executing `git remote rm origin` in your new git repo will remove the reference to `origin`.

You can read more about using and manipulating remotes [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Comment: that seems to remove the branches, the commits are there, but the branches no longer exist.  I am thinking if I had just done cp -r on the .git dir, rather than cloned it, i would have gotten what I wanted

Comment: That shouldn't remove any branches, `git branch -d [branchname]` would remove branches. The branches, if they were pulled to your local repo, should still be accessible. That being said, you will still have the commit history, yes. That's just part of git. If all you wanted was the files without the version control then yes `cp` probably would've been the way to go.

Comment: not sure why the branches were not there,  but I had not done a pull, I started with a clone of the existing repo.  Anyway thanks for the help, I went back and started with a copy rather than a clone, I will post what I did on an answer